# Why is Monad of sort Set1?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, agda, dependent-type

I've been trying to encode the Monad typeclass in Agda. I've gotten this far:

```
module Monad where
  record Monad (M : Set → Set) : Set1 where
    field
      return : {A : Set} → A → M A
      _⟫=_ : {A B : Set} → M A → (A → M B) → M B
```

So a Monad 'instance' is really just a record of functions that gets passed around. Question: **Why is `Monad` of sort `Set1`?** Annotating it with `Set` gives the following error:

```
The type of the constructor does not fit in the sort of the
datatype, since Set₁ is not less or equal than Set
when checking the definition of Monad
```

What thought process should I be going through to determine that `Monad` is `Set1` rather than `Set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agda has an infinite hierarchy of universes `Set : Set1 : Set2 : ...` to prevent paradoxes ([Russell's paradox](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/g53cfr/l20.html/l20.html), [Hurkens' paradox](http://code.haskell.org/Agda/test/succeed/Hurkens.agda)). `_->_` preserves this hierarchy: `(Set -> Set) : Set1`, `(Set1 -> Set) : Set2`, `(Set -> Set2) : Set3`, i.e. the universe where `A -> B` lies depends on the universes where `A` and `B` lie: if `A`'s is bigger than `B`'s, then `A -> B` lies in the same universe as `A`, otherwise `A -> B` lies in the same universe as `B`.

You're quantifying over `Set` (in `{A : Set}` and `{A B : Set}`), hence the types of `return` and `_⟫=_` lie in `Set1`, hence the whole thing lies in `Set1`. With explicit universes the code looks like this:

```
TReturn : (Set → Set) → Set1
TReturn M = {A : Set} → A → M A

TBind : (Set → Set) → Set1
TBind M = {A B : Set} → M A → (A → M B) → M B

module Monad where
  record Monad (M : Set → Set) : Set1 where
    field
      return : TReturn M
      _⟫=_ : TBind M
```

More on universe polymorphism in [Agda wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism).